# Yii2 get value from view file to controller

Tags: yii2

In controller file i print this, 
in controller am getting NULL after printing.

how to the know if button is clicked ?

```
var_dump(\Yii::$app->request->post('submit'));
```

In view file

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
            'id' => 'button',
        ]); ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('submit', ['name' => 'submit', 'value' => 'submit_1', 'class' => 'btn']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: `\Yii::$app->request->post('submit'));`  'submit' should be the model class name. if you're not sure what it is:  `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: If you doesn't have input fields your  \Yii::$app->request->post(); is always null. anywhere you can do :  $model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post()); and then var_dump($model);